# How to create type with models only in prisma && typescript

Tags: typescript, types, prisma

I needed a type that contains models only that's why I took type of Prisma Client and excluded Functions bu it doesn't work

My code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

type models = Exclude<InstanceType<typeof PrismaClient>, Function>;
```

Comment: Prisma provides type definitions that reflect your model structure. These are part of the generated `@prisma/client` node module. To learn how to use the type definitions, do check out the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#type-definitions)

Comment: Your models already exist on @prisma/client, you can do this and use your Prisma models in Typescript @Rufat
`import { PrismaClient, Session, User } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default prisma

export { User, Session }
`